# How to fix touchscreen on my Acer c720p

Tags: acer, touchscreen, chromebook

I have an issue with the touchscreen of my Acer c270p (it's a Chromebook).

The past two weeks, I was using chrome OS AND ubuntu thanks to crouton, but to save place, I decided to entirely remove Chrome OS and to install a fresh ubuntu distribution.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits with unity. After the install, everything was working fine except two things : the touchpad and the touchscreen.

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.jdpfu.com/2014/04/18/easy-acer-c720-ubuntu-14-04) to fix the touchpad and I added this lines to set up the sensibility in the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-cros_touchpad.conf` file :

```
Section "InputClass" 
    Identifier      "touchpad peppy cyapa" 
    MatchIsTouchpad "on" 
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
    MatchProduct    "cyapa" 
    Option          "FingerLow" "10" 
    Option          "FingerHigh" "10" 
EndSection
```

And now the touchpad work fine but I don't know how to fix the touchscreen. Does someone have an idea ? Do you think that it will be fix with the kernel of Ubuntu 14.10 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acer C720P Touchpad and Touchscreen are not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575457/acer-c720p-touchpad-and-touchscreen-are-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Hey.

This answer is probably a litte late, but (thanks to the author **lukabirsa** ) there is a great script [HERE](https://github.com/visionect/c720p) on how to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the Acer C720 and C720P (with many links to additional fixes for Kernel 3.13).

Have a nice weekend.

P.S. if you run Kernel 3.17 or newer, you don't need to fix the Touchpad and Suspend functionalities. On the opposite, I have no idea how to put the Touchscreen to work, but I'm working on it...

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer but I fixed my issue by installing the last stable Kernel (3.17). Thanks to that, the touchpad and the touchscreen works fine.

Good evening,

Damien