# Acer C720P Touchpad and Touchscreen are not working

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu in a **Chromebook Acer C720P** but neither Touchpad nor Touchscreen nor Microphone are working, I have flashed the ROM using John Lewis help and Ubuntu 14.04 was installed from scratch.

https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/

Any suggestion will be appreciate!

Comment: Did you use ChrUbuntu or Crouton? Also is your chromebook Acer C720 or Acer C720P

Comment: Hi @ethanbmnz, it is an Acer C720P (I omitted the P - It has touch screen)... About the method I used John Lewis' method, I know it is not ChrUbuntu since I used it before but It didn't work fine for me, but I don't know if there is a difference between Crouton and what I done.

I used this script: https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download

Comment: Crouton allows switching between ChromeOS and your chosen crouton target without rebooting. ChrUbuntu means you have to reboot your Chromebook if you're in ChromeOS and want to use Unity/Ubuntu. Why are you flashing John Lewis's ROM? If you want to reinstall ChromeOS, make a recovery USB/SD card via the chromebook recovery utility [http://tinyurl.com/chromebookrecoveryutil ], wait until the recovery USB/SD card has been made, then shut down your chromebook, take out your SD/USB, press and hold `esc` and `refresh` then press the power button. Insert your SD/USB card and wait.

Comment: [14.04 c720p scripts](https://github.com/visionect/c720p).

Comment: The scripts mostly just install some new kernel modules. According to [this Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173418&p=34) the drivers are in Ubuntu's linux-3.16.7-ckt4 so you could try just [upgrading the kernel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).

Comment: Thanks @ethanbmnz, but I don't have ChromeOS and I don't want to use anymore since I felt it limited the machine a lot, that is why I used another method in order to delete everything and install just Ubuntu.

Comment: @bain, I just followed the upgrading kernel instructions from that post and it WORKED!!!! Could you please answer me question with that information in order to have documentation, and I will also like to mark your answer as the correct one since you really deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linux-3.13 kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 does not have drivers for the C720P touchpad and touchscreen. You will need to install linux-3.16.7-ckt4 or later. You can upgrade the kernel by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).